# Taking specific order of differences of elements in a vector, MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have the following vector:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

I want to take the the difference between the `third` element and the `first` (`A(3)-A(1)`)

and then `fourth` and `second` element (`A(4)-A(2)`) and so on.

How do I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use this:

```
A(3:end)-A(1:end-2)
```

Comment: @Kamtal Thanks! That was an easy one :-)